# Why doing Backup-SPFarm for our sharepoint 2013 will update the sql databases "Last Database backup"

Tags: 2013, administration, backup, sharepoint-farm

we have SharePoint enterprise 2013, and i run the following command to do a farm backup:-

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory  \\****\backups\ -BackupMethod full -BackupThreads 10 -Force
```

now on the generated backup folder i got many .bak files ranging from 2kb size to 10 GB... also i have noted that for our sharepoint sql databases the "Last Database backup" date will be updates as follow:-

[image]

so can i conclude that the `Backup-SPFarm` will mainly do a pure sql databases backups ? also what are the .bak files which have small sizes such as 3 kb ?

Answer (score 5):

`Backup-SPFarm` does a few things:

- Backups all applicable databases. This also updates the `Last Database Backup` entry
- Exports information from the configuration database (which cannot be restored)
- Backups the search index

This is why you see smaller files along side your database backups.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply. so if we are doing `Backup-SPFarm` then we do not have to take sql backup from the sql database itself? as we will have redundant data? is this correct?

Comment: That's correct, however I usually encourage taking SQL backups and use `Backup-SPFarm -ConfigurationOnly` instead.

Comment: can i know why you prefer to do it in this way? based on my reading running this command `Backup-SPFarm -Directory  \\****\backups\ -BackupMethod full -BackupThreads 10 -Force` will allow us to get a full backup for every setting,configuration and data we have...

Comment: In a good number of farms you would use SQL transaction log backups/incremental backups. Using `Backup-SPFarm` breaks the log chain which causes problems restoring to a particular point in time.